# Why am I getting object is not callable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code:

```
import json
data=json.load(open("data.json"))
print(data)
data("rain")
```

gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: What were you expecting to happen? What does the data look like?

Comment: Good question. I just guessed that the OP wanted to access an entry of the `data` dictionary and was simply using the wrong syntax...

Answer (score 2):

Your Python `dict` syntax is off. Assuming you want to access the `rain` key of your `data`, you must use the `[]` operator.

```py
import json
data=json.load(open("data.json"))
print(data)
data["rain"]  # <--- change this
```

Python thinks you are calling a function (using `()`) and thus tells you that a dictionary cannot be called as a function!

Answer (score 1):

Two options below

```
import json
with open("data.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    rain = data["rain"]  # option 1 assuming you are sure that "rain" is in the dict
    rain = data.get("rain","no rain for you")  # option 2 if you are not sure that "rain" is in the dict
```